# SendEcho ERROR: sending to ICMPv6 packet to [2a06:98c1:3121::7]: (101) Network is unreachable

Tags: squid, ubuntu-20.04, icmpv6

we are using (Ubuntu 20.04 / Squid server / running on Azure) we are getting bellow error,

SendEcho ERROR: sending to ICMPv6 packet to [2a06:98c1:3121::7]: (101) Network is unreachable

We are not using IPv6, IPv6 already disable in network file. iptables and firewall already disabled

Can you please help to advise for resolve this issue...

Regards-Dinesh Taiwal

Comment: What do you mean by "disable IPv6 in network file"? Entirely switching off IPv6 needs to be done via a kernel parameter.